# ExFat HDD changed to NTFS after power interrupt

Tags: partition, ntfs, exfat

I installed on my iMac with Sierra the Paragon NTFS tool. I copied some files from NTFS to the ExFat partition and then suddenly the mac was hanging and rebooting. I was sure it wasn't good for the HDD, because it was in the middle of a writing task.

So my Partitions on the external HDD are:

```
HDD 1: Partition 1: Mac Recovery 250GB, Apple HFS 
HDD 1: Partition 2: Files 750GB, ExFat
```

After a reboot I checked the HDD, and my Recovery Partition was still the same. But the ExFat didn't show up anymore. In sudo diskutil list I saw that the partition is now listed as NTFS - WHICH IS WRONG.

So far I learned that NTFS and EXFAT have the same Partition Code 07 ([Restore partition type to NTFS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128883/restore-partition-type-to-ntfs))

Any tips for it? Did Not touch the HDD further. I just clicked hang out and took it by side.

Would buy the same External HDD, and make a 1:1 copy. Tips for this? Tips for solving the problem? Does a Windows computer helps maybe, or ruin more? Any idea what went wrong?

Delete and make a new partition is not a solution!